# Is there a right answer for question 3? Am I missing something here?

Tags: sequences-and-series, logic

So I was trying to learn logical reasoning from a textbook and this is one of the first questions solved. I'm able to solve the questions except for the 3rd one. Analysing it I think there is no valid option.
Am I missing something?

> [image]

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: Since you're a new contributor, I have answered your question and not downvoted your post. Here forward, it would be best if you include in questions *what you have tried* to adhere to community standards, so we can better help you! If you found the answer helpful, do not forget to upvote/accept the answer. If you have any questions, let me know.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Let's talk about the options of Question $3$, one at a time. Since box $W$ is delivered on Wednesday, box $Z$ is delivered on Tuesday. The only days left to think about are Monday, Thursday, and Friday.

(a) Suppose $U$ is delivered on Friday. Since $X$ cannot be delivered on Monday, $X$ must be delivered on Thursday. So, $T$ must be delivered on Monday. This is not possible due to condition (ii). So, (a) is false.

(b) Since $Z$ is delivered on Tuesday, (b) is also false.

(d) We already saw in (a) that $U$ cannot be delivered on Friday. Suppose $U$ is delivered on Thursday. In this case, $X$ cannot be delivered before $U$, since we are not allowed to deliver $X$ on Monday (and other days before Thursday are booked by $Z$ and $W$). On the other hand, if $U$ is delivered on Monday, then $X$ cannot possibly be delivered before $U$. Hence, (d) is false as well.

Only (c) remains and it is easy to check that (c) is indeed possible. The following sequence of deliveries make (c) possible:

1. Monday - $U$
2. Tuesday - $Z$
3. Wednesday - $W$
4. Thursday - $X$
5. Friday - $T$

Comment: But if U is on Monday then X needs to be on Wednesday by token of (iii) given in the question. Therefore there's no proper answer right?

Comment: @Noobie9000 That's incorrect. (iii) only says that **if** $X$ is on Tuesday, then $U$ is on Monday. It says nothing about when $X$ is not on Tuesday. In particular, **do not infer that**: $U$ is on Monday implies $X$ is on Tuesday. Only one direction of that implication is given.

Comment: Thank you! Just one last doubt, is (ii) a two way assertion because it says "must"?

Comment: No! (ii) is not a two-way assertion. Only (iv) is a two-way assertion. All "if then" statements are one way implications. Hope this helps! Don't forget to upvote/accept the answer if it helped you, and keep in mind to explain what you've tried the next time you ask a question.

Comment: Thank you so much!